# How to call CreateUser function manually in asp.net membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

How to call CreateUser function manually in membership provider in asp.net 4.0
using register control

I am not talking about custom membership provider,Just want to call createuser manually

```
<p class="submitButton">
    <asp:Button ID="CreateUserButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" 
        Text="Create User" ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup"/>
</p>
```

above code is copy from register.aspx, I could found movenext command

Comment: Check out this [video](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication/creating-user-accounts-programmatically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call it directly as seen in  http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-user-accounts-cs

Reference for `CreateUser()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/library/d8t4h2es.aspx

Comment: thanks very much.One more thing could you please tell me how I override MoveNext CommandName that I paste in my question.